# Share Flask-SQLAlchemy between two Flask apps

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two Flask apps running with a domain dispatcher (based on [this guide](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/appdispatch/)).

I'd like to share my models between the apps. Is it safe to have the `SQLAlchemy` object in a shared location and just call `db.init_app` with both applications?

This is my project structure:

```
app_one/
├ __init__.py
├ database/
│ ├ __init__.py
│ └ models.py
└ ...
app_two/
├ __init__.py
├ database/
│ ├ __init__.py
│ └ models.py
└ ...
shared/
└ ...
dispatcher.py
```

This is `dispatcher.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask
import app_one
import app_two


class Dispatcher:
    def __init__(self, config_file, app_one_config_file, app_two_config_file):
        self.app_one = app_one.create_app(config_file, app_one_config_file)
        self.app_two = app_two.create_app(config_file, app_two_config_file)

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        host = environ['HTTP_HOST']
        if host == 'app_two_domain.com':
            return self.app_two(environ, start_response)
        return self.app_one(environ, start_response)


def create_app(*args, **kwargs):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.wsgi_app = Dispatcher(*args, **kwargs)
    return app
```

Currently both `app_one/database/__init__.py` and `app_two/database/__init__.py` contain:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy
```

And in both `create_app` functions:

```py
from .database import db
db.init_app(app)
```

I'd like to move `db` into `shared/database/__init__.py`, and then either:

- call `init_app` with both apps, or
- make `Dispatcher` a subclass of `Flask`, call `init_app` in `Dispatcher`, and then register the Flask-SQLAlchemy extension with both apps with `app.extensions['sqlalchemy'] = _SQLAlchemyState(db)`.

What's the right way to go about this? (Splitting `app_one` and `app_two` isn't an option.)

(Note: this is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33126391/share-sqlalchemy-models-between-flask-and-other-apps), since both of my apps are Flask apps.)